# positioning images from website in google

Tags: html, image, positioning

On my website I have two pictures:

```
<a href = "/pathtofile/product_name_product_sign.jpg" rel="lightbox[gal]">
<img src = "/pathtofile/thumbs/product_name_product_sign.jpg" title = "Product Name, Product Sign, Product Small Info" alt = "Product Name, Product Small Info, Product Sign, Product Add Info"  rel="lightbox[gal]" />
</a>

<a href = "/pathtofile/fotoname-product_name.jpg" rel="lightbox[gal]">
<img src = "/pathtofile/thumbs/fotoname-product_name.jpg" title = "" alt = "" />
</a>
```

The second one is on the first position in google graphics. The first one is not even indexed. I've searched for product_name, product_sign and all the combinations. I even asked google for the whole picture name, alt, title -
 still nothing.

Do you have any idea why the first picture is not indexed (it has everything I've found in the internet about positioning pictures - the right name, alt, title) and the second picture is on the first position (wrong file name, no alt, no title)?

Thank you in advance. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a Google-Webmaster-Account. There you can ask google to index and crawl your whole site again.